# Can't completely reset Linksys E1200

Tags: router

I purchased a Cisco Linksys E1200 router, and I opted out of the Cisco Connect software. Once I did that, I was able to set the WPA2 password. Now, when I go to log in to the administration area of the router (192.168.1.1), it is completely different software (it is a purple-colored admin area, firmware 2.00.02, BEFSR41). Here's what it looks like:

[image]

Now, I'd like to install Connect, just so I can change the SSID and WPA2 password, but I can't because it fails when I try to install it (it can't connect).

If I can, I'd like to use the legacy Linksys firmware that is used on the WRT models.

Answer (score 1):

The "[BEFSR41](http://homesupport.cisco.com/en-us/support/routers/BEFSR41)" is a completely different router from the "[E1200](http://home.cisco.com/en-mea/products/routers/E1200)".  The BEFSR41 is a simple 4-port router (older) with no WIFI capabilities, whereas the E1200 has wifi & such.

Are you sure you're corrected to the correct router?  Do you have 2 routers on the same LAN?  It's possible you have an IP conflict and the "newer" router lost the arp race.

Comment: Also possible the E1200 has been connected to the BEFSR41 router and set up in bridge mode, and has a different IP . . .